# Can I serialize an arraylist so that I can store it in a .dat file?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to store an arraylist of a type I made, inside of a dat file so that the data isn't lost every time I close the program.  I've never done anything with serialization before, from looking at other questions on this site I think it's what I want.  Any help or insight is vastly appreciated!

Comment: All the objects you put inside the `ArrayList` must also be serializable.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implements [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) ,So you can serialize it. But remember that ArrayList is just a collection of items, so make sure that all the items are also serializable. Here is an example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class ListSerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add("a");
        lst.add("b");
        lst.add("c");


        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("foo.dat"); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
            oos.writeObject(lst);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<String> deserialized= new ArrayList<>();

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("foo.dat");
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);){
            deserialized = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();

            System.out.println("deserialized = " + deserialized);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```